# Run Time Error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set while URL data Scripting in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting

> Run Time Error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

while URL data Scripting

I am getting this error at the end of my code where I supposed to execute my code i.e. popup.click.

One thing I noticed if I run this below code step by step with the help of <kbd>F8</kbd> i was not facing such error but I am facing this error if I execute the code with the help of **Run Button**.

One More thing I just want to mention that when I execute the code with **Run Button** popup value shows nothing as i check.

```
        Sub GoToWebsiteTest()
        Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium
        Dim tags As Object
        Dim tagx As Object
        Dim repo As Object
        Dim popup As Object
        Dim Element As HTMLButtonElement
        Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
        Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument

        i = 0
        Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
        sURL = "https://oneview.myurl.in/"
        With appIE
            .navigate sURL
            .Visible = True
        End With

        Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        appIE.document.getElementById("Username").Value = "xxx"
        appIE.document.getElementById("Password").Value = "xxxx"

        i = InputBox("type")

        appIE.document.getElementById("txtcaptcha").Value = i

        Set tags = appIE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

        For Each tagx In tags
        If tagx.Type = "submit" Then
           tagx.Click
        End If
        Next

        Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set popup = appIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_gridUser_ctl00_ctl04_lnkG2")

' Here I am getting Object variable or With block variable not set error

    popup.Click
```

Comment: Might be that there isn't enough time between the two line when run normally, try to add `DoEvents` just before `popup.Click`

Comment: @R3uK Sir, I have Tried the same.I add the code **Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.readyState <> 4 :DoEvents:Loop** code but still the error not get rectified.

Comment: Yeah I saw that you used it there (there, it is used to wait for the page to load), but I'm suggesting that you **add it in between `Set popup = ap...` and `popup.Click`.**

Comment: @R3uK Sir, I have tried that as well Sir but I got same error.am I supposed to define different variable for popup other the **Dim popup As Object**

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if you have the MsgBox or if it works :

```
Sub GoToWebsiteTest()
    Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim tags As Object
    Dim tagx As Object
    Dim repo As Object
    Dim popup As Object
    Dim Element As HTMLButtonElement
    Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument

    i = 0
    Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    sURL = "https://oneview.myurl.in/"
    With appIE
        .navigate sURL
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    appIE.document.getElementById("Username").Value = "xxx"
    appIE.document.getElementById("Password").Value = "xxxx"

    i = InputBox("type")

    appIE.document.getElementById("txtcaptcha").Value = i

    Set tags = appIE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

    For Each tagx In tags
    If tagx.Type = "submit" Then
       tagx.Click
    End If
    Next

    Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop



    Set popup = appIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_gridUser_ctl00_ctl04_lnkG2")

    DoEvents
    If Not popup Is Nothing Then
        popup.Click
    Else
        MsgBox "popup is not defined!", vbOKOnly + vbCritical
    End If

    '''rest of your code
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the issue with **Do event** So I have change the same and tried this below code which is working fine.

```
Sub GoToWebsiteTest()
Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim tags As Object
Dim tagx As Object
Dim repo As Object

Dim Element As HTMLButtonElement
Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument

i = 0
Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
sURL = "https://oneview.myurl.in/"
With appIE
    .navigate sURL
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

appIE.document.getElementById("Username").Value = "xxx"
appIE.document.getElementById("Password").Value = "xxxx"

i = InputBox("type")

appIE.document.getElementById("txtcaptcha").Value = i

Set tags = appIE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

For Each tagx In tags
If tagx.Type = "submit" Then
   tagx.Click
End If
Next

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

Dim popup As Object
Set popup = appIE.document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_gridUser_ctl00_ctl04_lnkG2")

popup.Click
```